# Codeigniter routes, routing - for class

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to route:

**site.com/add-your-business** to **site.com/addyourbusiness**

Can you do that with the -

this does not work:

```
$route['add-your-business'] = "addyourbusiness";

$route['default_controller'] = "home";
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

I have the controller addyourbusiness set up but getting this page error:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /add-your-business was not found on this server.
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: As per documentation, the order of routes matters. Perhaps there is another route over-riding it.   Show the rest of them.

Comment: Does a controller named `addyourbusiness` contained in `application/controllers/addyourbusiness.php` exist and have an `index()` method?

Comment: solved it, it was in the .httaccess file not set correct

Comment: Please post your answer below and then accept it.